# how to modify special bit in ip packet with openflow?

Tags: networking, sdn, openflow, openvswitch

We've already known that `ovs-ofctl` provides many actions to modify packets like `set_field`, `load`, `move`...

but I can't find a suitable action or actions combination to modify a bit in the IP packet destinations field.

In other words, when we received packets the destination ipv6 field is `2020::1` or `2020::2`, we make the destination field become `2010::1` and `2010::2` by OpenFlow rules with `ovs-ofctl`.

I try to assemble `set_field`, `load`,`move` and others to do this, but it seems that it doesn't work.

Can we achive this simply by `ovs-ofctl` or not?

Comment: Hello, I am looking for the same in Mininet-Wifi for OpenFlow's rules. Can you suggest any tutorial to extract data from 802.11 MAC Header

Answer (score 0):

I used `NXM_NX_IPV6_DST` field and `load` action to resolve this problem on openvswitch bridge by adding a flow 
as follows

```
ovs-ofctl -O openflow13 add-flow br0 "priority=60000,ipv6,ipv6_dst=2020::/16,actions=load:0x2010->NXM_NX_IPV6_DST[112..127]"
```